# AMFI: allowing exception handler - because the handler was set by master-entitled process ´launchd´, VirtualBox

Tags: launchd, virtualbox, sandbox

I installed **macOS Sierra** 10.12 **like Guest** on **VirtualBox 5.1.10** on my MacBook Air with **macOS Sierra** too.

I facing errors! 
I login with difficulties an when I can, raise the error and I need to log in... the machine is not halt totally.

Here the video with the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xALbh0S9FwQ

For me is difficult to extract all Logs.

```
AMFI: allowing exception handler for ´WindowServer´ (813) because the handler was set by master-entitled process ´launchd´ (1)
AMFI: allowing exception handler for ´loginwindow´ (812) because the handler was set by master-entitled process ´init´ (1)
AMFI: allowing exception handler for ´loginwindow´ (812) because the handler was set by master-entitled process ´launchd´ (1)
IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 0, llk 1, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 3, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0

Some times:

SandboxViolation: fontd(1594) deny(1) file-issue-extension /Network/Library
SandboxViolation: languageassetd(544) deny(1) network-outbound /private/var/run/mDNSResponder
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**I want to know what solve it, and unsterstand what happens!**

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I found my problem!

I was using in **VirtualBox 5.1.14**. Type:`Mac OS X` and Version:`Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan (64-bit)` the problem raise up!

But using Version:`Mac OS X (64-bit)` works perfectly.

Comment: Indeed, this helped as well me. I am using VirtualBox 5.0.16 r105871. Thanks